# What do the Blue Lines in Lego 42145 (Airbus H175) step 34 mean

Tags: technic, instructions

In Step 34 there are three dotted blue lines shown on the assembled piece. I have thoroughly examined the build so far and am pretty certain it is right but I cannot figure out what the dotted blue lines are trying to tell me.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This indicates that you have to align the parts as shown in the step. In this case the white and the gray half beams share the same axle and you have to make sure they are aligned properly otherwise the mechanism doesn't work

Comment: That is so useful Joost - I, indeed, had the small grey and yellow elements 90 degrees out. Easily fixed though. Thank you for the help.